# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid - Column Type: Switch

Tags: oracle, switch-statement, oracle-apex

I've added an Interactive Grid to my page and one column I've set to column type "Switch". The whole grid is editable.

I have set the "Settings" for the Switch-column to the following values:

```
On Value: 1
On Label: Yes
Off Value: 0
Off Label: No
```

Running the page displays this column not as a toggle button when in edit mode, but as select list.
What has to be set to show the end-user a toggle button for input?

Thanks for any tipps,

Chris

Comment: Try going to Shared Components > Component Settings > Switch. What's the default Display Style for your Switch items?

Comment: @kfinity Yeah, that's it. It was set to select list, now I've changed it to switch and it is working fine.